# How can I test a database connection with CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, database-connection

I'm trying to learn CodeIgniter, but unfortunately many of the tutorials they list on their wiki are several years old and, based on others' comments, don't work on the newest version of CodeIgniter.

I did find one that didn't have any negative comments - on [IBM DeveloperWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-codeigniter/index.html#icomments)-  but I can't get it to work. Everything up until the form submit is fine, but after I submit I get a blank page and nothing is sent to the database.

How can I test/troubleshoot a database connection in CodeIgniter? I know my settings (as far as host, dbname, username/password, etc.) are correct because I'm using them successfully with a plain vanilla PHP site.

Edit to add: alternatively, can anyone point me to a recent beginner tutorial that works with the recent version? I don't need an MVC tutorial; I'm familiar with the design pattern. I just need to learn CodeIgniter.

Edit to add database.php file:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$active_group = "default";
$active_record = TRUE;

//$db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['default']'hostname'] = "myHostName.powwebmysql.com";
$db['default']['username'] = "myUserName";
$db['default']['password'] = "myPassword";
$db['default']['database'] = "codeigniter"; //yes, database is called codeigniter
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";


/* End of file database.php */
/* Location: ./system/application/config/database.php */
```

EDIT: error message when adding database load to constructor:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Welcome::$load
Filename: controllers/welcome.php

Line Number: 6
```

where line 6 is  $this->load->database();

Comment: sounds like your paths are not set up correctly...could you show us some code?

Comment: I've just tried that IBM tutorial's code with CI 1.72 and.. it works fine :-)...

Comment: @rabidmachine9 - from what I was able to gather from the tutorial, all connections are set up in the application/config/database.php file. I've posted mine above, minus some details.

Comment: you need to load database, in your controllers constructor add the line:$this->load->database(); if there is a db related problem it will give out a message that there is a problem with your db connection

Comment: @rabidmachine - that makes sense, but there's nothing in any of the sample code that looks like that. How is it that trix above was able to make the code work without that? Also, I added that line to the controller contstructor shown in the tutorial, and got an error. See original post for error message.

Comment: @rabidmachine - I moved the $this->load->database to the model, as suggested in several help files, and no more error, but still no dice.

Comment: @trix - did you just download the sample code file and upload the entire thing? Or actually type in the code he shows on screen in your existing CI 1.72 install? I tried typing the code, and it didn't work. When I downloaded the entire zip file and just extracted and uploaded to my host (without changing the code, only my database login info) it worked. So either his code, as shown, doesn't work in the newer version, or there are pieces of code needed that he didn't actually cover in the text of the tutorial.

Comment: I downloaded his code and add it to my CI 1.72 clean installation. And it worked (with configuration changed).... But his complete source code wasn't working because of some (I cant remember) deprecated function(s) (I use php>=5.3). I haven't checked his explanation nor his code extracts in tutorial though.

Comment: but are you sure you are editing the right controller?because it seems to give an error in the welcome page(sorry if that sounds obvious but I felt like asking :)

Comment: @rabidmachine9 - the welcome controller IS the one used in the tutorial.

Comment: ok... probably there is nothing wrong with the connection maybe you can display more of the code you are using or ,even better, start another tutorial...?

Comment: Yup, started a new tutorial - the doctrine one mentioned below. Works with absolutely no problems (well, I did just run into an issue, but that's another post and has nothing to do with the database connection.)

Comment: An old Q and just a guess but don't forget there's an `autoload` config file which loads (any libraries/helpers you choose) for every request. It's common to put the database library in there.

Comment: I came here from Google by searching "codeigniter test database connection", why are the answers about ORMs and Codigniter tutorials when that was merely a side note in the question?

Comment: @WesleyMurch - I'm not sure I understand why you downvoted my question, when it's the answers you have an issue with. I did not supply the answers.

Comment: Sorry @EmmyS, must have been in a rush looking for an answer and was frustrated that you accepted one that does not even attempt to answer the question in the title. Perhaps your question was not focused enough which is why it solicited these answers. This post is high in Google results but rather useless, perhaps you will edit it to reflect the real question you're asking.

Comment: WHat is 
"bumped to the homepage" ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some more recent beginner tutorial for codeigniter:

I enjoy the Jeffrey Way series video series.

http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-1/
http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-2/
http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-3/
[http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-4-newsletter-signup/](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-5-crud/)
http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-5-crud/

Comment: I saw those; unfortunately I'm having issues getting the videos to play. I'll keep trying, though.

Comment: I went through those tutorials, they are fine. In fact, I learnt codeigniter with the help of these tutorials. I had many issues which transferring my application from localhost to live, But i gradually resolved them.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'myUserName';
$db['default']['password'] = 'myPassword';
$db['default']['database'] = 'myDatabaseName';


/** Do not change the below values. Change only if you know what you are doing */
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8"; 
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_unicode_ci";
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;
```